# I can’t bind standard interface Zenject ITickable to class as AsTransient(). Tick() not called

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, zenject

I have a `Timer` class that implements the standard Zenject `ITickable` interface:

```
Timer: ITickable {
    public void Tick() {}
}
```

I want to create a new instance of `Timer` for every class that asks for it.

I do this (I want bind `ITickable` to `Timer`):

```
Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<Timer>().AsTransient();
```

I get dependency, but method `Tick()` is not called.

And if I change the registration to AsSingle:

```
Container.BindInterfacesAndSelfTo<Timer>().AsSingle();
```

the method `Tick()` is called normally.

How can I get a new instance of `Timer` with `ITickable` AsTransient()?

Comment: Can't reproduce on fresh project with zenject. Ensure you properly set up your contexts and installers and all bindings are really executed.

Comment: Installer and binding are ok. There might be some kind of bug. 
People here have encountered similar things.
https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject/issues/240.   
what version of the Unity and Zenject are you using?

Comment: Unity 2021.3.18f1; Zenject 9.2.0; I installed my installer into scene context.

Answer (score 0):

`TickableManager` is a manager that is responsable for IxTickable interfaces.
It gets a list of instances by injection. So when Zenject binder injecting dependencies in classes, it looks for certain provider that  implements method to get exact object. So when you use .AsTransient it calls transient provider. And its instruction is to return a new instance, when someone is asking for it. So as `TickableManager._tickables` is a `List<ITickables>` that injected as well, the instance created by transient provider for this list is also brand new.

So you have 3 options here:

1. You can force add instances of Timer in TickableManager.

```cs
Container.Bind<Timer>().AsTransient()
.OnInstantiated<Timer>((_context,_object)=> 
         _context.Container.Resolve<TickableManager>()
         .Add(_object)
   );
```

2. You can bind Timer with different id's. But this can only be justified in rare cases. In common it is a bad practice.

```cs
   Container.Bind(typeof(ITickable),typeof(Timer)).WithId(1).To<Timer>().AsSingle();
   Container.Bind(typeof(ITickable),typeof(Timer)).WithId(2).To<Timer>().AsSingle();
```

3. You can use `GameObjectContext` for each object. And if you are trying to create some sort of collection of game entities: enemies, weapons ,NPC, etc, this approach is the best. You just have to add `GameObjectContext` to the root of an entity prefab. And then create installer for this context, where Timer should be binded .AsSingle.

That was really tough question. It took several hours to find out the solution. I've already regretted taking on this question.

P.S. Don't be affraid to press F12 and Ctrl+F12 in your IDE to seek something in external libraries. You gain important experience by acting like this.